# How to know which indicator you are on with CarouselView in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I a using the CarouselView and I can successfully load in items! Yey, so far so good. But now when i reach the 2nd item, I try to do a specific function that will only happen in the 2nd index.

Right now i seem to have figured out when im on the 2nd page al though the log is writing a lot of things in the log, but when i transition to the 3rd page, or back to the 1st page, i have lost count (programmatically) of where I am.

```
   <CarouselView BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                          IndicatorView="indicatorView"
                          VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                          Margin="25,0"
                          Scrolled="CarouselView_Scrolled"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding BindingContext.Intro, Source={x:Reference ParentView}}">
                <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                    <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                       SnapPointsAlignment="Center" 
                                       SnapPointsType="MandatorySingle"/>
                </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Text}"
                                       FontSize="Large"
                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                       FontFamily="Helvetica Neue"
                                       TextColor="DimGray"
                                       FontAttributes="None" />

                        </AbsoluteLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>
```

Code behind:

```
    async void CarouselView_Scrolled(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemsViewScrolledEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.CenterItemIndex);

        if (e.CenterItemIndex == 1)
        {
            if (Transitioning == false)
            {
                Transitioning = true;
                await ParentView.ColorTo(Color.White, Color.FromHex("#161825"), c =>
                {
                    ParentView.BackgroundColor = c;
                    Transitioning = false;
                }, 500);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Transitioning = true;
            await ParentView.ColorTo(Color.FromHex("#161825"), Color.White, c => ParentView.BackgroundColor = c, 500);
            Transitioning = false;
        }
    }
```

What logic do i need to add in my frontend to successfully monitor if im on page 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ItemsViewScrolledEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.itemsviewscrolledeventargs?view=xamarin-forms) has a `CenterItemIndex` property that tells you which item is in the center view

or you could use the [CurrentItemChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.carouselview.currentitemchanged?view=xamarin-forms) event

Comment: not lookin smooth when i try to do my animation though.

Comment: for some reason it doesnt do the smooth ColorTo. "ParentView" as u see in the code is the x:name of the View that i change color of

Comment: it doesnt just give me one indicator in log, it spams it over 8 times. i belive that is the issue. i tried solving it with a boolean, but still it appears buggy

Comment: generally scroll events fire multiple times as the scrolling occurs.  That's why you probably want to use CurrentItemChanged instead.

Comment: yea, but that one didnt have the "CenterItemIndex".

Comment: you haven't actually explained what it is you're trying to accomplish, so I have no idea why that's relevant

Comment: know which page i am on, but the CurrentItemChangedEventArgs gives us "e.CurrentItem" that u can just checkup with a model and an ID easily. thx

Comment: cool to see that ur still here. u taught me a lot back in 2016 when i began studying xamarin.